Where do HTTP Requests from Google Colab originate from?
Say I am sending HTTP requests to an API on Google Colab python notebook, and I was wondering if the network I am sending them through can monitor the requests. Basically if I am working on a school network /company network, I understand they can see that I am on Google Colab, but can they see where the requests are sent to? My understanding is that these are sent from Google's data centers/cloud servers and not visible to the network.
Nothing Tried here,
